# How to get only Simple products from cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product, quote, simple-product

How to get only simple products from cart as currently i am getting configurable product also.

currently i need to check with an if condition

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $itemsd = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach ($itemsd as $key => $value) {
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($value->getProductId());
            if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){ 
                continue;
            }
        }
```

how to get only simple product not configurable product.

Comment: have you tried to change the typeId to simple?

Comment: its done by using $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there  :

```
  foreach($itemsVisible as $_item) {
         echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName();
    }
```

Comment: Yes correct 
Have you any idea how to get its custom option like Colour and size ?